# Parse datetime with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to parse the following datetime with the following format:

```
library(lubridate)
a <- "2004-05-07 18:24:58.666424"
```

I tried the following, but returned NAs

```
b <- lubridate::mdy_hms(a)
c <- lubridate::mdy(a)
```

Could anyone please explain how to parse this. I am also fine if lubridate is not used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `lubridate`, you can specify that your seconds have a decimal with the special `S!` or `OS` formats; see `?parse_date_time` for more parsing options.

```
> parse_date_time("2004-05-07 18:24:58.666424", 'ymd HMS!')
[1] "2004-05-07 18:24:58 UTC"
```

Alternately, it seems to parse fine with just the usual default `"ymd HMS"`:

```
parse_date_time("2004-05-07 18:24:58.666424", 'ymd HMS')
```

or the shorthand

```
ymd_hms("2004-05-07 18:24:58.666424")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
options(digits.secs=6)
as.POSIXct(a,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%OS")
#[1] "2004-05-07 18:24:58.666424"
```

Answer (score 0):

mdy=Month day year, your data is setup as ymd

Try ymd_hms or ymd